# Google Analytics with gtag.js - Difference between UA vs GA tag

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'm configuring my Google Analytics to work with `gtag.js`. This is a new account and I'm not dealing with any pre-existing analytics code or tags.

From: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs

[image]

From my Google Analytics Console (Admin section)

[image]

**QUESTION**

I was expecting to get a `GA-` tag from my Google Analytics snippet. But instead I've got a `UA-` tag. What is the difference between these 2 types of tags?

Answer (score 1):

Usually all the values of `GA_MEASUREMENT_ID` match the pattern of:

```
UA-<some numbers>-<some numeber>
```

so there's no problem with your value of tracking ID and it should work just fine